# Determining which vertex of a triangle one is computing in openGL ES vertex shader

Tags: opengl-es

I'm writing a WebGL program that draws a bunch of triangles to the screen. I'm using indirect addressing, so something like this:

```
gl.drawElements(gl.TRIANGLES, list.length, gl.UNSIGNED_SHORT, 0);
```

Is there any way for the vertex shader to know which vertex of a triangle it is processing? (among the three vertices in the order given by the list, i.e., the first, second or last)

Answer (score 1):

You can use additional integer attribute in stride alongside with vertex coordinates, texture coordinates, normal, etc. to check ID of vertex.

If you target OpenGL ES 3+ you can use `gl_VertexID` - https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/es3.0/html/gl_VertexID.xhtml

Comment: Doesn't that just tell you the index of the vertex in the list of vertices, and not whether or not it is the 1st, 2nd or 3rd vertex in the triangle being drawn?